# WordPress customization manualy by editing html

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hello I got wordpress theme , and have some knowledge about coding in
html ,css but wordpress is new for me.

I want to edit or comment out some things in my theme . But can't find source file for this , I can find header and footer , but content or home page I could't.

Maybe you know where I can find such information or you know where i find
this files . List of files I have in theme is :

```
 - @layout.php
 - archive.php
 - attachment.php
 - comments.php
 - footer.php
 - functions.php
 - header.php
 - index.php
 - page.php
 - post.php
 - search.php
 - side-bar.php
 - side-bar-left.php
 - singel-event.php
```

Answer (score 0):

*index.php* - is the template main page
*page.php* - is the template for pages

...
A detail explaination could be found on [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files).

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress we don`t have a structure like normal html pages. They have a hierarchy of files.

The content depends of its type *post, category, page* and so on.

Thats one thing that make Wordpress very eficient.

You can read more about the structure of wordpress  on [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Architecture_1.5) and [Wordpress Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Each theme is different, so it`s hard to point to you the exact file you are looking for.